# check if a 5-digit number is in a list based on place value

Tags: python

In Python, I am trying to compare a list of 10 5-digit numbers to three 5-digit number inputted by a user. 
For example, if one of the numbers in the list was 46590 and the user inputted 46509 it would show that the user only got the first three numbers correct.

The list is in a txt file. Here's what I have coded so far:

```
name = input("Enter the file name: ")


number1 = str(input("Enter in your first lottery ticket: "))
number2 = str(input("Enter in your second lottery ticket: "))
number3 = str(input("Enter in your third lottery ticket: "))

f=open("lottery.txt")
exs=f.readlines()
exs = [x for x in exs if x.strip()]
mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in exs]

for line in mylist:
    if line == number1:
        print("entire number equal")
    elif line[0][0] == number1[0]:
        print("first digit equal")
    elif line[0][0] == number1[0] and line[1][0] == number1[1]:
        print("first and second digit equal")
    elif line[0][0] == number1[0] and line[1][0] == number1[1] and line[2][0] == number1[2]:
        print("First second and third digit equal")
```

I tried using Boolean expressions but I kept getting error messages. Now, when I run the code above it prints out "first digit equal" twice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the fact that `True` and `False` evaluate to `1` and `0` in python and just take the sum of booleans to determine how many are correct:

```
win = "46590"
guess = "46509"

print(sum(a == b  for a, b in zip(win, guess)))
# prints 3
```

You can also loop through if you want to report for each value:

```
win = "46590"
guess = "46509"

for i, correct in enumerate(a == b  for a, b in zip(win, guess)):
    print(f"digit {i} correct: {correct}")
```

Prints:

```
digit 0 correct: True
digit 1 correct: True
digit 2 correct: True
digit 3 correct: False
digit 4 correct: False
```

If you have a list of winners you can use the same technique to see how many are correct in each one:

```
winners = ["16129", "46590", "79562", "47597", "25649", "11111"]
guess = "46509"

print([sum(a == b  for a, b in zip(win, guess)) for win in winners])
# [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0]

# get max correct:

print("Best:", max(sum(a == b  for a, b in zip(win, guess)) for win in winners))
# Best: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do this and match at occurence:

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])  
f.col1 =  pd.Series([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8]) 
f.col2 =  pd.Series([3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 2, 0, 8])
f.index+=1
f['Match'] = f.col1==f.col2 
temp = (f["Match"] != True).cumsum()[f["Match"] == True]
temp2 = f.groupby(temp).apply(lambda x: list(x.index))
print(f'Your matches are at: {temp2.to_list()}')

# Your matches are at: [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist refactoring your code slightly.

Since your input is small, we can afford to read the entire thing at once.

```py
name = input("Enter the file name: ")

num_1 = str(input("Enter in your first lottery ticket: "))
num_2 = str(input("Enter in your second lottery ticket: "))
num_3 = str(input("Enter in your third lottery ticket: "))

with open("lottery.txt") as file_1:
    raw_lines = file_1.read()

file_lines = (line.strip() for line in raw_lines.splitlines())
file_lines = (line for line in file_lines if line)
```